# why my git init command auto create a .gitignore file

Tags: git, macos

Git auto crate `.gitignore` file when I run `git init` under a android project, but it doesn't do this when I under a java(intelliJ) project.

I use a mac, and the `which git` shows `/usr/bin/git`. It seems like that the git is the mac official git. Why this(auto create .gitignore) happen? And how can I control(config) it?

---

**Update**:

It's the IDE create `.gitignore` file when I create the project. Sometimes a person is easy to enter into the misunderstanding of thinking...

Comment: You sure it's not an IDE you have opened that detects that you created a repository there and provides the .gitignore for you?

Comment: The contents of the `.gitignore` will provide big clues to what created it.  Please post it OP.

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake think the .gitignore was created before `git init`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git does not create `.gitignore` files on `git init` - if so, presumably that behavior would be mentioned in the documentation for `git init`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init.

Something else is creating the .gitignore file - there isn't really enough information here to say what.  Some IDEs such as IntelliJ store *IntelliJ-project-specific* configuration in a local `.idea/` directory when you're working on a project - so I would not be surprised if some Android IDE was creating the file (per Lasse's suggestion).

I don't know what you mean by *How can I control (config) [the .gitignore file]?* but you are free to delete it or modify it as you wish - see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore for the official documentation.